# Cybersource capture through CIS payment

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, credit-card, cybersource

How can I send a capture request to cybersource using hybris CIS payment. Below is the method I am using but it is giving me 102 as response code with reply message as

```
The following request field(s) is either invalid or missing: auth_request_id
```

I am able to see the capture request when I login to EBCtest but it does not have any details.

Below is the code which I am using, trying to capture the amount by hard coding the amount, transaction id and authorization ids

```
CisPaymentRequest cisPaymentRequest=new CisPaymentRequest();
                    //cisPaymentRequest.setParameters(new AnnotationHashMap(getAnnotationHashMap()));
                    cisPaymentRequest.setAmount(new BigDecimal(58.55));
                    cisPaymentRequest.setCurrency("USD");
                    final CisPaymentTransactionResult captureResult = getCisClientPaymentService().capture(CLIENT_REF, "single",new URI("https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor?auth_request_id=831000"),"D99OZS1FU15J", cisPaymentRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

The authorization request ID you are sending is invalid: auth_request_id=831000

Here is an example of a valid authorization request ID: 5499176942776634304004

The authorization request ID is returned by CyberSource in the response to an authorization request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it got resolved-

I changed the url and corrected the transaction id

Authorization ID

OLD - https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor?auth_request_id=831000

Correct- https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/831000

Transaction id

OLD - D99OZS1FU15J

Correct - 5512968196316020204007

```
CisPaymentRequest cisPaymentRequest=new CisPaymentRequest();
                //cisPaymentRequest.setParameters(new AnnotationHashMap(getAnnotationHashMap()));
                cisPaymentRequest.setAmount(new BigDecimal(58.55));
                cisPaymentRequest.setCurrency("USD");
                final CisPaymentTransactionResult captureResult = getCisClientPaymentService().capture(CLIENT_REF, "single",new URI("https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/831000"),"5512968196316020204007", cisPaymentRequest);
```